# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' when using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I'm trying to solve a strange error in a strange context. A user is running some of my [code](https://github.com/minillinim/GroopM) and has encountered this TypeError:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/groopm/cluster.py", line 692, in twoWayContraction
(k_partitions, k_keeps) = self.HP.houghPartition(k_dat[:,0], l_dat)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/groopm/cluster.py", line 1377, in houghPartition
imgTag=imgTag)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/groopm/cluster.py", line 1520, in recursiveSelect
(m, ret_point, accumulator) = self.houghTransform(tData.astype(float)[startRange:endRange,:], imShape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/groopm/cluster.py", line 1749, in houghTransform
flat_indices = Rs * cols + Cs
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

The [specific piece of code](https://github.com/minillinim/GroopM/blob/62d078d5a5700be0082d97b61073c4259da83a3f/groopm/cluster.py#L1749) which is throwing this error is trying to do a Hough transformation in Numpy land (NOTE: I have imported np.sin as np_sin etc.):

```
cos_sin_array = np_array(zip([np_sin(dth * theta_index) for theta_index in range(cols)],
                             [np_cos(dth * theta_index) for theta_index in range(cols)]))

Rs = np_array(np_sum(np_reshape([p * cos_sin_array for p in data], (d_len*cols,2)),
                     axis=1)/dr).astype('int') + half_rows

Cs = np_array(range(cols)*d_len)

flat_indices = Rs * cols + Cs
```

In this code, cols and half_rows are ints, dth and dr are floats and data is a numpy array with shape (cols, 2) (ie. a set of coordinates)

I can make the same TypeError easily on the python prompt using:

```
3 + range(9)
```

Using:

```
range(9) + 3
```

gives:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

But of course with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
3 + np.array(range(9))
np.array(range(9)) + 3
```

Is OK. Now, the exact line which causes the error is this one:

```
flat_indices = Rs * cols + Cs
```

The types of the members here are:

```
flat_indices = numpy.ndarray * int + numpy.ndarray
```

But the error gives the indication that:

```
Rs * cols (numpy.ndarray * int) is an int
Cs (numpy.ndarray) is a list
```

I am very confused. Has anyone encountered something like this before? I'm happy to go on a fishing trip, does anyone have any idea where I should cast my line? I am completely out of ideas and I need to find some kind of resolution to this problem.

NOTE: The user is a reviewer of the [academic paper](https://peerj.com/preprints/409/) (link is to preprint) describing this code so I can't make contact with them directly, nor can I get hold of the data which crashed the program, nor can I get detailed information about the system it's running on. Also, this crash is somewhat deep into the running of the code.

So for all intents and purposes I can't reproduce it with the original data, nor can I give some test data which will reproduce it.

Finally, here is the code in question cut out of context for anyone who wants to try get the error.

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='raise')

(rows, cols) = (10000, 10000)
data =  np.array([[4,4]] * cols)
d_len = len(data)
half_rows = rows/2
if half_rows == 0:
    half_rows = 1
    rows = 2
rmax = np.hypot(rows, cols)
dr = rmax / (half_rows)
dth = np.pi / cols
accumulator = np.ones((rows * cols))*255

cos_sin_array = np.array(zip([np.sin(dth * theta_index) for theta_index in range(cols)],
                             [np.cos(dth * theta_index) for theta_index in range(cols)]))
Rs = np.array(np.sum(np.reshape([p * cos_sin_array for p in data], (d_len * cols, 2)),
                                axis=1)/dr).astype('int') + half_rows
Cs = np.array(range(cols)*d_len)

flat_indices = Rs * cols + Cs
```

I'm happy to try anything that's suggested, thanks.

EDIT:

Based on Akavall's comment I can produce the exact TypeError by setting Cs to:

```
x = []
k = 0
for cs in Cs:
    if k == 10:
        x.append(cs)
    else:
        fred = [cs]
        x.append(fred)
    k += 1
Cs = np.array(x)
```

(after it's been set initially of course...)

So then Cs looks like: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], ... , 9, [10], ... ]

I know this isn't what's happening in the code. But I also don't know why this makes the TypeError. If anyone can explain what's going on under the hood to raise that particular TypeError on this particular array, it'd be a help and may help me get closer to the solution.

Comment: It's definitely odd.  Aside #1: why are you importing half of numpy but referring to it as `np_array` instead of simply `np.array`?  Aside #2: you're throwing away a lot of the benefits of using numpy in the first place by using Python-level code like `zip` and list comprehensions instead of taking advantage of numpy's vectorized ops.

Comment: I think `Cs` or `Rs` is either an array of lists or contains a list.

Comment: @Akavall: interesting idea!  `Rs` looks more likely than `Cs` to have wound up with `object` dtype somehow.

Comment: This looks like a numpy versioning error. Do you know the target numpy version that this is being run on? I am running on 1.5.1 with no errors. (side note: why are `d_len` and `cols` different variables?)

Comment: @DSM Aside #1: It's a habit, and perhaps some premature optimisation. I call these numpy functions LOTS, so I like to use from X import Y type syntax, but many of numpy's functions are the same/similar to builtins and math, hence the np_. It may not be a problem in this exact bit of code but across the project it crops up and I want consitency. Aside 2: Faster is better, the numpy here is to avoid nested for loops but this is the best I could do, happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: @ebarr: unfortunately I can't get the numpy version the reviewer is using. What makes you suggest it's a difference in numpy versions? I can run this on numpy versions 1.7.1 and 1.9.0 with no difficulty. As for the aside. In the example given I know that d_len and cols are the same but when the code is running in the wild d_len and rows may be the same as cols or 1 bigger. The rows and columns are related to the accumulator while the data is independent and is the returned value of previously called functions.

Comment: @minillinim Different numpy versions handle arrays of dtype object slightly differently, which can cause problems when adding arrays.

Comment: Yes. I see what you mean. Tested the code snippet on version 1.6.1 now too with no problem either. It seems that it must be the Cs array that causes the problem. But that would mean that `np.array(range(some_int)*some_int)` is returning something other than an ndarray with dtype('int'). Can anyone make numpy do this?